How does the industry (not hobbyist) cope with the variance of the current gains of BJTs of the same type when designing an amplifier?
This essay says,

Many digital multimeters, DMMs have a capacity for measuring the gain of a transistor. This can be quite a useful function, especially for checking whether a transistor is still functioning or not.
Generally this type of measurement is incorporated in the lower end digital multimeters as it is not a particularly accurate test and is generally more appropriate for hobbyist and 'quick check' style measurements of the transistor function.

How does a designer in a company (rather than a hobbyist) designing an amplifier deal with the variance when they can't even get an exact value of the current gains with an DMM? Do they have some method that can ignore the variance of \$h_{fe}\$?
Let's say, for common emitter amplifier, is there some standard/canonical way in the industry to do the design work?
How good is the method told in this video
says, which says the gain of a BJT common emitter amplifier (as in the picture below) roughly given by \$gain =- R3/R4\$. Like, would a high end headphone like YH-5000SE Headphones or a studio headphone like ATH-M70x use this design method for their audio amplifier?

What about other type of amplifiers? Like, common base, common collector BJT amplifiers. Can you point to some material (books, videos, papers, notes pdf, etc.) that talks about the practices that are actually used in the industry?

Industry is a peculiar focus: the industry today essentially never (in terms of units) uses this circuit -- indeed the average audio device uses zillions of CMOS logic gates, handling digital signals for the most part. Current or voltage gain aren't direct factors in their performance at all.

The answer is simple and it's taught on early electronics courses when transistors are introduced.
Basically any circuit that depends on hfe being a specific value is bad, basically the only circuits that should depend on hfe are the circuits that are used to measure hfe for you.
A much more sensible way to think of it is that when building a circuit, you generally require some minimum hfe to do the job, and use a transistor that can provide higher hfe, but not overdo it.
The circuits are designed in a way that when hfe varies within limits the effect is insignificant or simply small enough on the circuit output that it does not matter.
For example in the amplifier circuit you show in the question, the resistor values biasing the base and emìtter are chosen such that the base voltage and thus emitter voltage does not change much even if hfe varies e.g. between 50 and 400.
As long as the DC bias point stays within reasonable limits, it does not affect the AC signal gain much at all.
Of course this is just a very simple example.
More complex circuits may improve upon on using building blocks that might compensate for the changes in hfe by e.g. using feedback.
Sometimes the transistors manufactured have so much variation that the manufacturer bins them for you. For example BC547 comes unlabeled and in A/B/C variants. The A variant has hfe in the range of 110-220, B has 200-450 and C has 420-800. The unlabeled has then a range of 110-800.

You mean, that company produce BC547's first, then test their $h_{fe}$ and then categorise BC547's into A/B/C according to the test result?


How does a designer in a company (rather than a hobbyist) designing an
amplifier deal with the variance when they can't even get an exact
value of the current gains with an DMM?

If the required circuit performance demands high accuracy and repeatability then, a single common emitter amplifier just won't cut-the-mustard. A very-high-gain circuit comprising several cascaded transistors will be used with negative feedback to restrict the gain to the required value with high stability and accuracy.
Alternatively, an op-amp is used or, an instrumentation amplifier. Basically anything that works better than a single stage common-emitter amplifier will be considered with the CE amplifier right at the bottom of the choice list.

Let's say, for common emitter amplifier, is there some
standard/canonical way in the industry to do the design work?

A CE amplifier is a last resort. There are several/plenty of better choices for many more target applications. Of course we learn about CE amplifiers first because this leads us into learning about differential amplifiers and, that in turn, leads us into negative feedback and op-amps (the main choice for a vast majority of amplifier applications).

What about other type of amplifiers? Like, common base, common
collector BJT amplifiers.

For the vast majority of applications in the industry we serve, barely none of the above. Of course there are corners and crevices (such as RF amplifiers above a few GHz) where we might consider the common-base circuit. There'll always be a small need for single BJTs circuit design.

would a high end headphone like YH-5000SE Headphones or a studio
headphone like ATH-M70x use this design method for their audio
amplifier?

This is entirely down to the user of the headphones and nothing to do with the headphone manufacturer but, I can say this as a general guideline; A CE BJT's distortion level will be significantly greater than a properly designed headphone amplifier and, it's output impedance will be wholly unsuitable for driving headphones.

A lot of time, money, and life's blood has been spent over many decades to deal with the impact of temperature on circuits. Fortunes have been made on thermally stable voltage references and current sources, for example, whether available as isolated parts or incorporated within larger integrated circuits. Some of that history is laid out for you in Linden T. Harrison's book, Current Sources & Voltage References. You have a lot of responses to go over and there's a lot to process, including (of course) Tim's comment to your question.
I'd instead like to focus squarely on your proposed circuit topology, treat it as a discrete circuit, and show you how it can be temperature-compensated. Whether or not this helps, I don't know. But I can take a shot at it.
I've created two circuits. One that uses your topology and one that includes a method for compensating against part variations and temperature variations. I'll run these two circuits over a wide range of operating voltages, too. (If you are interested in more detail about their design, you can reference the appendix found at this link.)
In order to exaggerate the problem, I've chosen to use a high voltage gain: \$A_v=30\$. This is because a high voltage gain in your standard topology mandates a much lower emitter voltage. This fact makes the problem stand out better.
Here's the run of the two topologies:

The top display shows the temperature and part variation compensated output (the left-side schematic that includes resistor RXa) and the bottom display shows uncompensated output (the right-side schematic that matches your topology.)
I think you can clearly see that temperature compensation does work pretty well. And now you can see one method to achieve it.
In addition to the distortion that may occur in some circumstances with your topology, corrected in the compensated circuit topology, the effective voltage gain also varies more widely when uncompensated for temperature and part variations.
We should expect to see \$20\cdot\log_{10}\left(30\right)\approx 29.54 \:\text{dB}\$. Here's the same schematic again, but run to focus on this aspect of the two circuits:

Note that the compensated circuit hits the voltage gain extremely closely: \$29.54 \:\text{dB}\pm 0.06\:\text{dB}\$. It's accurate and tight. (Consistent low distortion helps here.)
The uncompensated circuit varies from about \$28\:\text{dB}\$ to \$30\:\text{dB}\$, or about \$29 \:\text{dB}\pm 1\:\text{dB}\$ (in some cases due in part to added distortion.)

For all circuits employing discrete transistors, the design assumes worst case conditions, which in the case of \$h_{fe}\$ would probably be its lowest possible value, as quoted in the device's datasheet. The circuit designer usually makes the assumption that every such transistor will have that lowest possible \$h_{fe}\$.
If you then find that your chosen transistor's worst-case current gain is insufficient for your application, either use a compound transistor like a darlington pair, or choose a different one with better specs. In any case, the design is always driven by worst case specifications. Although unlikely, "worst case" could mean highest \$h_{fe}\$, if for some reason you require it to be low.
For audio applications, or any application in which distortion is to be avoided, the usual approach is to cascade several stages of limited gain, to obtain much more gain than is required, and then use negative feedback. In such an arrangement, individual stages don't need to be particularly linear (low distortion), because negative feedback permits tight control of actual gain, lowers output impedance, linearises overall response, and simplifies biasing.
This is the approach used in most linear designs, and since op-amps have already implemented all of this, you would usually use an op-amp instead of discrete transistors. There are of course occasions when no (affordable) op-amp has the characteristics you require, and discrete transistors are your only recourse. In such cases you must design with worst-case transistor characteristics in mind.
The circuit you showed would almost never be used alone in an audio application such as microphone pre-amplifier or headphone amplifier, since it is not particularly linear, and doesn't have sufficiently high input impedance or low enough output impedance. You might however find something similar employed as part of a larger, multi-stage system with negative feedback in a closed loop.
Low transistor \$h_{fe}\$ (which I will call \$\beta\$ from now on) in a single-transistor requires more base current to obtain the same output response. You are forced to sacrifice either high input impedance or low output impedance. The following design illustrates the need for low input impedance to guarantee similar quiescent state, whether \$\beta=20\$ or \$200\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Emitter degeneration with R3 provides some inherent negative feedback, and permits fine control of collector/emitter current. However, large variation in \$\beta\$ (\$h_{fe}\$) means that base current in each case is very different (shown on AM2). In order to keep base potential the same in both cases, so that emitter potential and the consequent emitter current also remains roughly the same, we must ensure that base current (AM2) is a very small fraction of current in the resistor divider R1 & R2 (AM1).
If base current were significant in comparison to divider current, base potential would change a lot with transistor \$\beta\$, and the quiescent state of the system would vary significantly depending on \$\beta\$. By using low values of R1 and R2, we ensure that base current is small compared to divider current, and base potential remains fairly constant, regardless of \$\beta\$. Ammeter AM3 shows roughly the same quiescent collector current in both cases, in spite of \$\beta\$ changing from 20 to 200.
You still get your voltage gain of ten, but the price you pay for \$\beta\$ independence is low input impedance, a heavy load on whatever is providing the input signal. You could increase all resistances in roughly the same ratio, to increase input impedance, but unfortunately you then raise output impedance, which is equally inconvenient.
Still, we must pay that price, usually by adding additional stages, each of which also needs to have immunity to varying \$\beta\$. One such approach might be to buffer the output using an emitter follower, permitting you to increase all resistances (left):

simulate this circuit
On the right I use a darlington pair with combined current gain \$20\times 20=400\$. I encourage you to change the transistors' gains (parameter "BF") to see how it affects quiescent state. I've used ridiculously pessimistic gains of \$\beta=20\$ to illustrate the dilemma. In practice most signal transistors have minimum \$\beta\$ closer to 50, and it won't be so difficult to design for \$\beta\$ independence.
Having said all that, the author's claim that \$\beta\$ measurement is "generally more appropriate for hobbyist and 'quick check' style measurements of the transistor function" is only true because of the word "generally". Manufacturers sometimes purchase transistors in bulk, and bin them according to gain (and/or other parameters), using only those from a particular bin for a particular role. I don't think this happens very often, as it complicates manufacture and repair, but it does happen.

Regarding your question:

the answer has been lying in my drawer for a long time, and that is:

If you want to make some changes, for example a different bjt or a well defined value of Rc, you have to check the terms under the root, which must always be positive otherwise you get complex values. To get positive values ​​you have to vary the voltage Vosw.

You better cite links to sources of images!

I drew and wrote everything myself with PAINT and Mathcad 15.

Cite your textbook if poss. Nice work Francesco. How do you like my sim?

In my life I found THD was easily measured by THD= (Vp+ + Vp-)/Vpp when normalized to Vavg =0. What are your thoughts?

Shortly after formula 6) the text from which I got the idea for the calculation of RB and something else is cited. for the load and bias lines I refer to the good old Millman & Alkias "Electronic Devices and Circuits".

I read what you wrote. It is all "holy-holy" and undoubtedly useful. The text I cited is a common text for students who are tackling the topic of bjt polarization for the first time. In that same text, the NFB and applications are treated much later, so I did not take into consideration the NFB.

what about THD and 10% error from 6:1 hFE range?

But if I get a bandwidth wide enough to let through, say, the first five harmonics for a square wave test signal , I shouldn't have significant harmonic distortion, I don't know in percentage terms.

I meant comparing the non-linear difference of a full swing +/- peak sine about 0 relative to the Vpp is equal to the sine harmonic THD by RMS method. Spectral distortion is visible in my sim but not calibrated and has some pixel artifacts.  https://tinyurl.com/227t2lfw you can slide the simulation fast to grow the spectrum samples then slow down. Distortion is mainly 2nd harmonic.

I need to read up on the subject, at the moment I could only tell you that 10% is not bad.

I was hoping you could read my sim. I've never read much in my career except datasheets and Pease.

Stability of gain comes with complexity and negative feedback.
Pre-amps will use high gain with lots of GBW to achieve high fixed gain with the precision of the resistor ratios, as the error function in this ratio depends on the error gain to NFB, negative feedback Rf/Rin. Since a single transistor has low gain compared to an IC with Aol = 1e6 typ, the single transistor gain must be much lower than the hfe.
Power Amps will use low gain (10 to 20 dB) as hFE drops at high current and so NFB gain is low since the total hfe is lower in a few stages of high current gain than Op Amps which then must use integrator (compensation) cap(s) to be unity gain stable.
A wide hFE variation is normal due to process methods like 50 to 200 is 4:1 or a 400% ratio.  The Japanese company ROHM sorts them for designers into different bins denoted by part suffix letters.
Nobody would seriously use an H bias for a low THD audio amp. It is just for learning purposes.  Since gain varies with Vbe and IC it reduces gain as Vce increases greatly. This yield comes at a reasonable cost.
The same is true for the variation in LED efficacy which is improved with low variation in Vf. Typically you might see specs of 3 to 3.6 for white but I used to buy custom LEDs at 3.05 with a 0.05V tolerance (3.0 to 3.1) in orders like 10k pcs and up for a small premium.
Here the gain Av=10 +/-10% for hFE from 50 to 300 (est.)  If you need proof I can provide an easy simulation.

The low THD is shown here in the simulation which is a result of reducing the Aol to Av = 10 with NFB using Rfb/Rin ratio = 10 where Rfb includes Rb||Rce+Rc.
Note how low Vbe pp is smaller than input due to NFB  R ratio. This is how hF design is done to reduce sensitivity to hFE.
In an Op Amp the NFB is far greater so the input is a virtual null. Vpp=0.
In MOSFET amplifiers the device also has a BETA function closely linked to Rds that determines voltage gain in linear mode. (But that is a different question.)


Buy parts specified to be as accurate as you need

if that's not possible, sort them yourself


Design an amplifier that isn't dependent on precise BJT gain – that's basically a no-brainer when you need an amplifier of specific gain. You'll basically always find a feedback path inside such an amplifier. AS you can imagine, commercial amplifier designs aren't of the "copied from second-semester textbook with smiling transistor superimposed" variety :)

Building a good audio amplifier would take feedback, a much more intense consideration of design decisions, thermal compensation, compensation to make the frequency response behave as desired… It's not going to be a single-transistor amplifier. In fact, headphone amplifiers would typically depend on integrated circuits, with external well-trimmed compensation.

Like, common base, common collector BJT amplifiers.

These aren't amplifier designs, these are just basics methods how to connect a BJT. These things can be part of an amplifier.

Can you point to some material (books, videos, papers, notes pdf, etc.) that talks about the practices that are actually used in the industry?

Well, that material would be aimed at electrical engineers at the end of their studies or after finishing their degree; in such studies, you'd start with getting a deeper understanding of active circuits, especially of operational amplifiers, dive into signal and control systems theory, acquire some experience in simulation of electric circuits. You'd then look at the landscape of existing amplifier ICs and choose whether one of them fulfills your needs (that's very likely), and what supporting circuitry you'll need for it. If you're working for the company designing such ICs, or high-power amplifiers that can't be implemented in ICs, you'd go ahead and dig into specialist literature and research papers – but pointing you to these would serve no purpose for you! You're missing a few years of education (yet! you seem to be learning!).
So, maybe hobbyist-transistioning-to-professional literature serves you better; Douglas Self's "Audio Power Amplifier Design Handbook" might be good for you.


Any practical design must work for a range of beta values (and temperature).

The classic single-transistor capacitor-coupled amplifier has not been used in products for many decades. Between symmetric designs (differential pair) and current source biasing beta variation is not a problem in bipolar circuits. This sort of design for bipolar circuits became common a few decades ago. A great many new designs use MOSFETs. It's not a bad idea to understand this kind of circuit, but be aware that it is...historical.




What about other type of amplifiers? Like, common base, common collector BJT amplifiers.

Common collector amplifiers have approximately unity gain, regardless of the value of \$h_{fe}\$. One need only ensure that the base current is sufficient to drive the required emitter current in worst case scenario.
Common base amplifiers have high voltage gain, but the input is the emitter, so the output current is approximately equal to the input current. Again, the designer need only ensure that the the available base current is sufficient to permit the required emitter/collector current.

The base current - as a small part of the emitter current - is an unwanted "byproduct"  resulting from the emitter current (it does not "permit" any other current).

@LvW How would you word the fact that if one wants a particular emitter or collector current, the circuit must be capable of providing a particular base current?

@ Math Keeps Me Busy - my answer: Normally, a suitable collector current (and corresponding resistors in collector and emitter legs)  is SELECTED with respect to the desired/required transconductance gm (and , of course, the available supply voltage). From this, the corresponding base current results with large uncertainties (B tolernaces). But a good design - as you probably know - will cope with this tolerances. That means: The base current does not "permit" the collector current - it is simply a part of Ie=Ic+Ib. The "heart" of the DC bias is the voltage Vbe, which  "permits" Ic and Ib.

@LvW, Yes, I agree with you about the workings of a transistor. My question is how you would explain to someone else, for example the poster of this question, the fact that the circuit must provide sufficient base current, if the circuit is to have the target emitter or collector current. This is a practical matter, regardless of whether the base current is a side effect of the base-emitter voltage.

@ Math keeps me Busy - I must admit that I do not understand your question.  When a circuit has a certain (finite) input resistance there will be, of course, a certain input current. Is it really necessary to EXPLAIN why the design should allow such a current? Even in case of an operational amplifier (where the input currents can be neglected, in most cases), it is necessary to allow these currents (DC connection to common ground). Comment: Perhaps I have misinterpreted in your contribution the word "permit".  Sorry, but this sounds as if Ib would be the cause (a precondition) of Ic.

Under the assumption that the input signal is applied directly to the base terminal of the BJT, the gain of the amplifier stage depends on the collector current (resp. the transconductance gm=Ic/Vt) only.
The variation of B (resp hfe) concerns the input resistance at the base terminal only.
This is because the BJT is a voltage-controlled device Ic=f(Vbe).
The variations of B (resp hfe) have a minor influence on the collector current, when there is a base voltage divider (for providing a fixed base potential Vb) which allows a current through both resistors that is at least 10 times larger than the expected base current.
It was shown that this concept (voltage divider at the base and a Ic-stabilizing emitter resistor Re) is the best method for biasing a BJT-based amplifier stage.
Example: When a common-emitter stage is designed according to these rules, it does practically not matter if you are using a BJT with B=100 or B=200. For equal operational DC operating points the voltage gain will not differ in both cases.
The base current (and its uncertainties/tolerances) plays a considerable role only when

another concept for biasing is used (only one resistor between Vcc and the base), or

when there is a resistor between the input signal source and the base termial.
============================================================


Final comment:  You have used the simplified formula Gain=-R3/R4.
Note that this expresson results from the more correct formula
Gain=-gmR3/(1+gmR4)=-R3/[(1/gm)+R4] for 1/gm<<R4 (transonductance gm=Ic/Vt)

"The BJT is a voltage-controlled device" -- No one outside of academia thinks of a BJT as a voltage-controlled device. To those of us who design actual working circuits, a BJT is a current-controlled device.

@ Davide Andrea - don`t you think that the content and the outcome of my contribution (in particuar, my example with two diffreent B values) shows that you are wrong? You only can understand and/or design new circuits when you now how the BJT really works.

It all depends on what the purpose of the circuit is, and what transistors you are using.
If it's low frequency, low current, then you have a large choice of transistors, all with hFE in excess of 100. There are standard methods using simple feedback to ensure that the transistor stays in the linear region. One is setting the base voltage with an emitter resistor to fix the emitter current. Another is using feedback from the collector to the base, to fix the collector voltage. Both are ways to design a transistor stage 'on the back of a beer-mat'.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With both circuits, start by assuming infinite hFE, so zero base current. In the circuit on the left, choose a base bias voltage of 1/3rd of the rail, which puts roughly the same voltage across emitter resistor, transistor, and collector resistor. In the right hand circuit, choose a collector voltage of half the rail, then choose the base potential divider to deliver 0.7 V to the base at that collector voltage.
Now, as an exercise left for the reader, calculate what the voltages and currents are around the two transistors in these circuits for finite hFEs of, say, 200, 100, or even 50. Let the base current flow through the bias resistance, and see what the change is.
High current power transistors tend to have a fairly low hFE, sometimes the low 10's. It's quite common to use a Darlington configuration, and then the current gain of the combined pair is often in the 1000 ballpark, usually large enough to treat as infinity.
If it's an RF application, where you need precise control of the bias voltages, for junction capacitance variation or maybe voltage breakdown, and/or you need precise current control to get output power while limiting heating, then you simply have to spend a few extra pennies and board area on an op-amp to measure the collector current/voltage, and to control the bias actively.
